# Counter in for loop java

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

I´m creating a simple text editor and in it, I have popup Window with 8 buttons and they will work as preset of the text size in the editor and I want the first button to be 2 and then next button +2 I have all this in a for loop but the int which handles the 2+ stays the same in the 8 rounds the loop goes. Could maybe some of you look at my code and see what I did wrong?

```
public static void texSizePreset() {
    for(int i=0; i < stylePresetButtons.length; i++) {
        int defaultFontSizePreset = 2;
        textSizePreset[i] = defaultFontSizePreset;
        String convertedFontSizeText;
        convertedFontSizeText = Integer.toString(textSizePreset[i]);
        stylePresetButtons[i].setText(convertedFontSizeText);
        defaultFontSizePreset += 2;
        System.out.println(defaultFontSizePreset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define `int defaultFontSizePreset = 2;` outside of your loop? You do realise it's getting reset at the start of every loop

Comment: You don't really need `defaultFontSizePreset` at all. Just use `(i * 2) + 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are initializing defaultsizepreset within the for loop take it out of the for loop and everything

```
    int defaultFontSizePreset = 2;
    for(int i=0; i < stylePresetButtons.length; i++) {
    textSizePreset[i] = defaultFontSizePreset;
    String convertedFontSizeText;
    convertedFontSizeText = Integer.toString(textSizePreset[i]);
    stylePresetButtons[i].setText(convertedFontSizeText);
    defaultFontSizePreset += 2;
    System.out.println(defaultFontSizePreset);
}
```